# How to pass attribute value change to angular 4 directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to implement Datatable in my angular 4 application. I created an directive and the data table is populating.

Now if i delete the table data, i could see visual disapperance of the row but datatable still holds my data. The solution to it is the directive should detect change in the data.

Will it be costly if using setInterval in the directive as it will be running an infinite loop.

Or the other idea i got was create attribute draw and redraw. But again the question how to keep a track on change in input attribute with no events occured.

**HTML Code**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" appDatatable [data]="roles" *ngIf="roles && roles.length">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Created By</th>
      <th>Created At</th>
      <th>Updated By</th>
      <th>Updated At</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let role of roles">
      <td>{{role.name}}</td>
      <td>{{role.description}}</td>
      <td>{{role.created_by}}</td>
      <td>{{role.created_at | date}}</td>
      <td>{{role.updated_by}}</td>
      <td>{{role.updated_at}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" (click)="update(role)">
          <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button" (click)="remove(role)">
          <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Directive Code**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery:any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDatatable]'
})
export class DatatableDirective implements OnChanges {

    table:any;

  @Input() data:any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { 
    this.initializeDataTable();

  }

   initializeDataTable(){
        setTimeout(()=>{
           this.table =  jQuery(document).find(this.el.nativeElement).DataTable();
           setInterval(()=>{this.watchData();}, 5000);
       });
  }

  watchData(){
   //I can watch the data change here. But is it a costly solution?
  }

  ngOnChanges(){ // not working
    console.log(this.data);
  }

}
```

Hope i was clear on my question.

In short, how to detect change in input to a directive.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the ngOnChanges function is like

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

}
```

Or is your post pseudo code? 
You have to add `SimpleChanges` to your imports.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: I had it working. I need to use setTimeout in the component to redefine the input change. Will post the working code down. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I got your point on SimpleChanges. The issue is the i am calling this.setTable on both of my init and onchange. So the datatable is called two times. Why is that ngOnchange and ngOnInit both are fired at same time.

Comment: First event that is fired is ngOnChange then ngOnInit. You can find the hole sequence here https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Got it .Thanks. It answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your efforts. Need to put setTimeout in component.js file.

**roles.component.ts**

```
onRemoveConfirm(row){

    _.remove(this.roles, (role)=> role === row);
    this.setDatatable();  

  }

setDatatable(){
     this.drawDatatable = false;
     setTimeout(() => { // added this setTimeout 
      this.drawDatatable = true;  
    });
   }
```

**role.component.html**
Here instead of passing data, took a boolean info to draw the table.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" appDatatable [draw]="drawDatatable">
```

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery:any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDatatable]'
})
export class DatatableDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    table:any;

  @Input() draw:boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { 


  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.setTable();
  }

  ngOnChanges(){
      this.setTable();
  }

   initializeDataTable(){
        setTimeout(()=>{
           this.table =  jQuery(document).find(this.el.nativeElement).DataTable();
       });
  }

  setTable(){
     if(!this.draw){
      if(this.table){
        this.table.destroy();
        this.table = undefined;
      }
      return;
    }
    if(!this.table){
      this.initializeDataTable();
    }

  }


}
```

Comment: remove this.setTable on ngOnInit as the datatable is initialized twice.